# How do I set HttpOnly on a session cookie in Rails 2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies, httponly

I notice that Rails 2.2 (currently edge) supports [setting HttpOnly on the session cookie](http://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1046-http-only-cookies-in-cookiestore).

Is there a way of setting it on a Rails 2.1 application without moving to edge/2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [written a monkey patch](http://gist.github.com/14086) to add this support to Rails 2.1, from the patch for Rails 2.2.

I've not tested on anything other than Rails 2.1, and your mileage may vary!

Answer (score 1):

Well it isn't supported, as you note, but you can of course [monkey-patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) Rails to do what you want.  Actually, the difference between directly patching your Rails v. monkey-patching in this case is very little, as either would be removed/reverted when you upgrade to 2.2.

In both cases you would look at that applied diff as a guide for patching 2.1 yourself - either through applying the patch directly (modulo any 2.1/edge differences), or by reopening those classes from your own code post-environment-loading to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `http_only` option to true in the cookie's options hash:

```
cookies['visits'] = { :value => '20', :http_only => true }
```